# Call to undefined method App\Models\Ads::links()

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I have this code in my controller

```
$ads = Ads::orderBy("element")->paginate(50);
return view("Frontend.all")->with('ads', $ads);
```

And into my view I would like display pagination links so I make this code

```
@foreach($ads as $a)
    {{ $a->name }}, 
@endforeach
{{ $a->links() }}
```

Problem is that I have an error like in title

> Call to undefined method App\Models\Ads::links()

Where problem is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your variable name is `$ads`, not `$a` :

```
@foreach($ads as $a)
    {{ $a->name }}, 
@endforeach
{{ $ads->links() }}
```

Comment: lol! seems like I'm not the only one who made this same mistake. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

you are accessing wrong object.it should be be `$ads` instance which has links method

```
{{ $ads->links() }}
```

You can read more  about pagination methods in laravel documentation api

https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Pagination/Paginator.html#method_links

Also Laravel official documentation has example similar to your requirement.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#displaying-pagination-results